# wxPython notebook have tabs be center top?

Tags: wxpython

How can I have the wxPython notebooks tabs be center on the top?

EXTRA TEXT TO MAKE IT LOOK LONGER EVER THOUGH IT IS A SIMPLE QUESTION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notebook tabs always start off in the top left for the native widget. The only thing you can change is which side the tabs appear on (i.e. top, left, bottom or right). You cannot control where on the side they appear.

You might be able to take FlatNotebook and hack it a bit to add this functionality since it is written in pure Python versus wx.Notebook which is wrapped C++.

Comment: Thanks you and your blog are a WEALTH of knowledge so thank you, I think now I am just going to go the custom route.